# Keyboard.FocusedElement is null, what are the possible causes?

Tags: .net, wpf, focus, keyboard-navigation

While keyboard navigating a WPF app, in one step, between one control and another, the `Keyboard.FocusedElement` is null. If there is no reference to this property in the code, which methods can cause this? Is there an `Unfocus` method for any control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way this could happen is if focus is on a control and then the `Focusable` property of that control is set to false.  `Keyboard.FocusedElement` would then be null.